# I want to fetch a file from my code folder to my js file automatically when the page loads

Tags: javascript, html, input, fetch

I want to fetch a file from my code folder to my js file automatically when the page loads so I can use in an audio visualizer. I don't have to fetch it from the users computer!

How do I do it?
I was trying to do it using fetch but I can only fetch from URLs now.
I want to use the file like this

```
    document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', function(e){
      this.fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
      }.bind(this));
      var _this = this;
    
    this.fileReader.onload = function(){
      _this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(_this.fileReader.result, function(buffer){
        if(_this.source) {
          _this.source.stop();
        }
        _this.source = _this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
        _this.source.buffer = buffer;
        
        _this.source.loop = true;

        _this.source.connect(_this.analyser);

        _this.gainNode = _this.audioContext.createGain();

        _this.source.connect(_this.gainNode);
        _this.gainNode.connect(_this.audioContext.destination);
        _this.source.start(0);
        
        _this.frequencyArray = _this.webgl.sphereG.attributes.aFrequency.array;
        _this.indexPosArray = _this.webgl.indexPosArray;
        _this.indexPosLength = _this.webgl.indexPosArray.length;
        _this.isReady = true;
      });
    };
  }
```

but instead of getting the user to choose a file from his/her computer I want to fetch a file from my the folder where this code lies automatically.

Comment: The code you are showing is code that runs when a user chooses a file from their computer. If the file you desire to load is in the same folder as the script file, it has a URL; the same as the script file, only using the file name of the file you want to load.

Comment: You cannot use `fileReader` without the user manually selecting the file. (the browser cannot access the local filesystem without permission). That's why you have to use `fetch()`

Comment: i dont want to access the local filesystem.
as i mentioned the audio file is already in the folder in which my code lies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for an `<input type="file"/>` then.

You might have success with

```
// if the HTML that's executing the current JavaScript is at 
// https://example.com/foo/index.html and audiofile.ext
// is in the same location as index.html (i.e. also inside foo),
// this would work:

fetch('audiofile.ext')
   .then(res => res.blob())
   .then(blob => {
      // do stuff with the blob
   });
```

See the [fetch docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).